# Haskell import declaration

Tags: haskell, syntax, module, import

I started to read about monad transformers and what puzzles me is `Control.Monad.CatchIO`'s import declaration which I see in many code examples:

```
import "MonadCatchIO-transformers" Control.Monad.CatchIO (finally)
```

What does this quoted token mean? I took a look at [the Haskell 98 Report's section on import declarations](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/modules.html#sect5.3), but this didn't help me understand.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Its a package-qualified import, which is a GHC extension.  The string is a package name.

See [Package-qualified imports](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0-latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#package-imports), from the ghc docs, for details.